Incorrect integration results in Adaptive Quadrature routine with periodic functions
I have just finished writing an iterative Adaptive Quadrature routine in C++ that uses the trapezium rule as a base. I plan on writing one using Simpson's rule next.
The routine is quite simple. The integral of the function $f(x)$ over an interval $[a,b]$ is approximated as
$$
\phantom{.}\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x) \approx \frac{b - a}{2}\left[f(a) + f(b)\right] = Q_0.
$$
The routine then splits up the interval into two halves, and approximates the integral as
$$
\phantom{,}\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x) = \displaystyle\int_a^m f(x) + \displaystyle\int_m^b f(x) \approx \frac{b - a}{4}\left[f(a) + 2f(m) + f(b)\right] = Q_1,
$$
where $m = \frac{a + b}{2}$ is the midpoint between $a$ and $b$.
If $\left|Q_0 - Q_1\right| > \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is some tolerance passed to the function, then the above steps are applied to the $[a,m]$ and $[m,b]$ intervals recursively. Else, the function exits and returns $Q_1$.
Here is my issue: when integrating $f(x) = \cos(2x)$ over the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, my routine computes the integral as $2\pi$, instead of $0$, as it should be. This is not just specific to $f(x) = \cos(2x)$, of course, but to any periodic function $g(x)$ in which $b - a = n\lambda\,,n\in\{2,4,6,\ldots\}$, where $\lambda$ is the range over which $g(x)$ is periodic, since that results in $f(a) = f(m) = f(b)$, the consequence of which is that $Q_0 = Q_1$, and so the interval is never divided further, and the function exits at level $0$ of recursion.
I can think of a few "brute-force" ways to deal with this, but would much appreciate any insight on more "standard" approaches to tackle this.
I'm aware that Adaptive Quadrature routines using the trapezium or Simpson's rule are far from the best, but they're sufficient for my needs, hence why I'm writing them.
For reference, I include my code below. Please note that I have just finished writing it, so have not included any optimisations yet at all (I have unnecessary function evaluations, extra additions, extra divisions, for example, as it stands).
template <numeric T, callret<T> F, uint64_t max_depth = 256>
HOST_DEVICE T trapquad(const F &f, T a, T b, T tol = 0.0625l/1024.0l, uint64_t *mdepth = nullptr) {
    if (mdepth)
        *mdepth = 0;
    uint64_t tree[(max_depth % 64) ? max_depth/64 + 1 : max_depth/64]{}; // fixed at compile-time
    const T global_a = a;
    const T global_b = b;
    T m = (a + b)/2;
    T f_a;// = f(a);
    T f_m;// = f(m);
    T f_b;// = f(b);
    T res = 0;
    T ires; // intermediate result
    T estimate;
    T error;
    T dx = b - a;
    uint64_t depth = 0;
    bool left = true;
    T numdx;
    T whole;
    char *s;
    do {
        start:
        f_a = f(a);
        f_m = f(m);
        f_b = f(b);
        estimate = (dx/2)*(f_a + f_b);
        ires = (dx/4)*(f_a + 2*f_m + f_b);
        if constexpr (max_depth)
            if (depth == max_depth)
                goto other;
        if (abs(estimate - ires) > tol) {
            tol /= 2;
            dx /= 2;
            left = true;
            b = m;
            m = (a + b)/2; // simplify later
            ++depth;
            // goto start;
        } else {
            other:
            // printf("a: %lf, b: %lf\n", a, b);
            res += ires;
            if (left) {
                a += dx;
                m += dx;
                b += dx;
                left = false;
                if constexpr (max_depth)
                    tree[depth/64] |= (1 << (depth % 64));
                // goto start;
            } else {
                if (mdepth)
                    if (depth > *mdepth)
                        *mdepth = depth;
                if (b + dx > global_b)
                    return res;
                if constexpr (max_depth) {
                    do {
                        tree[depth/64] &= ~(1 << (depth % 64));
                        if (!--depth)
                            return res;
                        a -= dx;
                        dx *= 2;
                        tol *= 2;
                    } while (tree[depth/64] & (1 << (depth % 64)));
                    tree[depth/64] |= (1 << (depth % 64));
                } else {
                    do {
                        if (!--depth)
                            return res;
                        a -= dx;
                        dx *= 2;
                        tol *= 2;
                        numdx = (b - global_a)/dx;
                        // printf("numdx: %lf\n", numdx);
                        whole = std::round(numdx);
                    } while (std::abs(whole - numdx) > 0.25);
                }
                a += dx;
                // b += dx/2;
                b += dx;
                // if (b > global_b)
                //     return res;
                m = (a + b)/2;
                left = false;
            }
        }
        // printf("Depth: %" PRIu64 ", a: %lf, b: %lf, dx: %lf\n", depth, a, b, dx);
        // sleep(1);
    } while (depth);
    return res;
}

Edit: what I have done, and will most likely keep, is implementing a ptol variable. If $f(a) = f(m) = f(b)$ within this ptol tolerance, then I force the integral to be subdivided further. I've made this behaviour optional.
I'll make this an answer eventually, if no one else answers.
